# What is the object moving across the ceiling in this stock footage?

Tags: identification, contemporary-history

It's a large cuboid box, looks to be around 2 feet by 1 by 1, tapered/bevelled at the edges, moving across an office ceiling at roughly 1 metre per second on a rail. The narration accompanying the footage talks about federal investigators looking into dodgy accounting in 1975 so it could be the FBI or SEC, or just random office stock footage not related to the date or subject.

It can be seen in this short [clip on twitter](https://twitter.com/tomrledger/status/1131834656465281024)

Screencap from the clip, object is between the heads of the two men:
[image: Picture of object]

Having moved to the right below the light fitting:
[image: Second picture of object]

This clip is from the [Barbie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbie) episode of [The Toys that Made Us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Toys_That_Made_Us), first season, second episode.

It appears to be stock footage, and the documentary gives the following credits at the end:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any more information on the source of the video?  If we know more about _where_ and _when_ it was filmed, we may be able to research what internal transport/communication systems were installed in that building at that date.

Comment: Afraid not, it's basically stock footage, used in the Barbie episode of The Toys that Made Us documentary on Netflix, 28 minutes in.

Comment: Do they state the source of the clip in the credits at the end of the documentary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an [Electric Track Vehicle system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_track_vehicle_system) (thanks to user AplusKminus for the suggestion). "The system utilizes independently driven vehicles traveling on a monorail track network, consisting of straight track elements, bends, curves and transfer-units for changing of travel direction"

[image: ETV system]

"ETV systems were primarily put on the market in the sixties by German company Telelift." This fits in with the likely era of the footage.

The shape of the object resembles this 1978 Telelift container:

[image: Telelift container]

This also explains how it seems to glide above the rail - the wheels are hidden by the sides of the rail.

These Siemens ETV containers also look similar:

[image]

Answer (score 35):

Confirming Brian Z and his answer: this is most likely a penumatic tube mail system. And strictly speaking: "What is the object moving…?" –
It's not a "cuboid box" but a [cylindrical container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube), also called capsule.

Most easily visible in this still:

> [image]

You see a darker edge on top, a lighter reflection of light at the bottom of the tube. On the right is a hanging fixture for the tube extending right to the bottom of the loghter reflection. It's really everywhere, but more pronounced to the right of the head:
you also see colour variations of the ceiling as the light passes through the tube. This is most visible to the left, where the lights appear lens-like distorted. Also, the darker upper edge extends from phase change lighting extends all the way across the picture. Tubes vary in size and can (now) take 50kg.

This is not a rail bound system: The "darkening" is not just the obvious shadow above the box/capsule. The colour isn't uniform across the whole tube. That is clearly independent from lighting the capsule. Reflections on a possible rail at the bottom are one thing, but that colour variation along the entire picture gives it away. The distortion of lights left of the pillar and the gradient from the tube to the right of the second head are incompatible with just "rail". These would need explanation, not capsule/box forms.

Exaggerated:

> [image]

[image]

[image]

In case the verbal descriptions are insufficient: *only* the glistening "rail" speaks *for* a rail system. But it is the lower edge of the tube, as these numerous hints would confirm, which a "rail" cannot explain:

[image]

Especially the last few frames to the right make the tube quite obvious.

These are still in use today.

Not only thinks the [German State Minister for Digitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothee_B%C3%A4r) that [these are still indispensible](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/politik/technik-aus-dem-19-jahrhundert-digital-staatsministerin-erklaert-notwendigkeit-von-rohrpost-im-kanzleramt/24240104.html).

They also look cool:

> [image] 
>   [image]

Source: [The Pneumatic Tube System (PTS)](https://parsianmedical.com/pneumatic-tube-system-pts/)

For a size comparison of possible systems, roughly "from that era":

> [image]
>   <sub>[A look at what’s left of NYC’s pneumatic tubes
>   Surprisingly, some buildings still boast functioning pneumatic systems
>   June 07, 2015 05:00PM](https://therealdeal.com/2015/06/07/a-look-at-whats-left-of-nycs-pneumatic-tubes/) and 
>   [Pneumatic Tubes In New York City](http://jasonfarman.com/delayedresponse/pneumatic-tubes-in-new-york-city/)</sub>

And they could be a bit larger still:

> [The Pneumatic Despatch](https://pneumatic.tube/history)
>   [image] [image]
>   [The London pneumatic tube mail train at its formative stage!](http://www.7dayadventurer.com/category/old-technology/)

More variety:

> [image] <sup>[src: Pneumatic tubes](https://yourmoneychoice.blogspot.com/2018/05/pneumatic-tube.html)</sup>
>
> [image] <sup>[src: Pneumatic Tube Systems: Spare Parts, Service and Support](https://www.swisslog.com/en-gb/healthcare/products/material-transport/pneumatic-tube-system-parts)</sup>
>
> [image] <sup>[src: 
>   Society Adventures: Exploring Stanford Hospital’s Pneumatic Tube System](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/obscura-society-adventures-exploring-stanford-hospitals-pneumatic-tube-system)</sup>
>
> [image] <sup>[src: Pneumatic Tube System / Carriers](https://www.conceptionsmg.com/anglais/capsule.html)</sup>
>
> [image] <sup>[src: Pneumatic sample transport](https://www.impautomation.com/Non-Ferrous/Pneumatic-sample-transport/)</sup>
>
> [image]
>   <sup>[Image: Photograph](https://www.abc.net.au/radionational/programs/latenightlive/pneumatic-tubes:-the-instant-messaging-technology-that-transfor/9866280) Showing An Operator Preparing To Feed A Carrier Holding About 500 Letters Into The Transmitter For Despatch Through The Tube From Brooklyn Post Office To New York General Post Office C 1899 ((Sspl/Getty Images))</sup>
>
> [image]
>   [image]
>    <sup>[Distroller Wərld Opens Los Angeles Flagship Store](https://patch.com/california/los-angeles/distroller-wrld-opens-los-angeles-flagship-store)</sup>

Comment: It's not clear to me that the darker area at the top isn't just a shadow from the box - it doesn't extend beyond the box itself - the two darker patches in the light strips are i think just gaps between the lights. The pneumatic tubes shown so far are a much smaller diameter and the cylinders don't resemble the box. Also the bottom of the box appears to be above the rail/reflection - plausible for a rail, not for a tube.

Comment: Suspended below - what you think is the reflection on the tube I think is the rail. The suspension hanger to the right could be for a rail or a tube. I don't think the quality of the footage is good enough for colour variations to be decisive. I'd be prepared to accept this answer if I could see a photo of a larger tube with a similar cylinder, from the same era!

Comment: I agree with you, but its travelling pretty slow compared to the pneumatic tube I remember seeing in a newspaper building in my youth.  That one arrived with a solid WHANG, whereas clip shows its about as fast as a lethargic cat walking.

Comment: In the future we will all be using pneumatic tubes for [transportation](https://zapatopi.net/inteli-tube/)!

Comment: I really doubt that this is a pneumatic system. Those seem to have higher velocity and most importantly: tubes. I think it is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_track_vehicle_system

Comment: @AplusKminus I think you're on to something there - the container at the bottom of this page has a similar profile: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/Telelift_1978.jpg/970px-Telelift_1978.jpg

Comment: @ledge The "dark" is not just the obvious shadow above the box/capsule. The colour isn't uniform across the whole *tube*, that is clearly independent from lighting the capsule. Reflections on a possible rail are one thing, but that colour along the entire picture gives it away. The distortion left of the pillar and to the right of the second head are incompatoble with just "rail". *These* would need explanation, not capsule/box forms.

Comment: @LangLangC They could be explained by a shadow from the rail - but ultimately I just don't think the video quality is high enough to draw any firm conclusions in that way. How do you explain the fact that the box seems to ride above the reflection? This would make sense for a car with wheels riding above a rail, not for a capsule inside a tube where the reflection would be in front of/obscuring the capsule.

Answer (score 24):

That's a [pneumatic tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube). The tube itself is transparent in this case, but the object you see moving through it is a capsule carrying documents, or maybe cash or other small objects. [They are still used](https://www.thestar.com.my/lifestyle/food/news/2013/12/24/a-new-way-to-deliver-food-via-tubes/) in some places (in that link, for delivering food), but were a common feature of most offices before the rise of computers and digital technology.

Comment: "Before", and while and after… [says](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/politik/technik-aus-dem-19-jahrhundert-digital-staatsministerin-erklaert-notwendigkeit-von-rohrpost-im-kanzleramt/24240104.html) one [State Minister for *Digitization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothee_B%C3%A4r) Considering how big this is, I assume it transports magnetic tape for mainframes?

Comment: I think it's a rail not a tube (I can see the rail now, I thought it was a light fitting before, will edit the question).

Comment: ^^^ Both good points. I'll leave my answer as it was, even though I'm probably a bit off base!

Comment: @ledge at the top you see a darker edge, and at the bottom a lighter reflection, just like what you'd expect with a transparent tube. That also solves the problem whether a monorail suspension goes through a light fixture or not. And in your first still to the right is also a hanger the extends exactly below the lower edge of the tube.

Comment: I'd say this looks  like a reasonable answer. Look at the appearance of the tubes in [this installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LQawqeGfh0) at the European Patent Office for comparison.

Comment: Banks with drive-through lanes in particular still use them. My pharmacy has one for its second drive-through lane as well.

Comment: A textile shop in UK my mother used to go to in the 1950s had something similar. When the customer paid, the money and bill were placed in a capsule, the assistant rang a bell, and it was shot up to Accounts/Cashiers Department, then returned with the change and receipt. As a child, I was fascinated - thought it was magic! ;-)

Comment: And here I was hoping it would be some ceiling-hugging Roomba.

Comment: I remember that department stores in USA used to use pneumatic tubes (for payments?) about 1960.

Comment: The box-thing in this movie is larger and slower than any pneumatic tube system I've ever seen. I agree with @KeithMcClary (below) that this looks more like a special effect from a movie. Also note that the original clip from Twitter ends with an image of a Mattel, Inc stock certificate of some sort.

Answer (score 7):

I must respectfully disagree with existing answers to this interesting question.

As Keith McClary noted, this object has a larger diameter than most pneumatic capsules. Capsules have reason to be small, both to increase pressure per area on their exposed surface, and so that tubes with wide bends can fit into buildings. According to [an archived article from capsu.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20100111070801/http://www.capsu.org/history/telegram_conveyors.html), "Most tubes were 2 1/2 inches in diameter, with 3 inch diameter tubes being used where traffic was particularly heavy." What is shown in the video may be a foot in a diameter.

No tube at all is visible here. Rather, the mystery object rides atop a thick, rigid rail, casting a tight shadow upwards which might otherwise be distorted by the light passing through a glass pipe. This rail's hanger therefore has to be offset to avoid fouling the payload. Despite the camera's movement, the hanger visible at the right seems to consist of a single L-shaped element. No tube would be hung in this fashion.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube) suggests a normal speed of 7.5 to 10 meters per second for pneumatic capsules. The object in the video is moving not much faster than the men walk, or maybe a tenth of a capsule's speed.

The "MATTEL, INC." stock certificate that follows is a good clue that could lead to a precise answer. While Mattel is a toy company, the object is not obviously a toy, though it could be a prototype of one.

The object is used for some kind of transit but as we do not recognize its form, it is probably a purpose-built container of specific dimension, a shuttle borne along the rail by a chain drive or worm drive system.

Comment: With all due respect to Wikipedia, they are wrong about the speeds. Take a look at this video of a [pneumatic installation at the European Patent Office](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LQawqeGfh0).  Modern medical transport systems often use capsules about the size of the one shown, and much larger pneumatic capsules were used by the [Hamburg pneumatic post](http://www.douglas-self.com/MUSEUM/COMMS/pneumess/hambg-compare.jpg) from the 1950s (similar systems were also used in London, Chicago & New York)

Comment: @sempaiscuba What you link is labelled as an "installation in the european patent office by Yvonne Lee Schultz, 2004". She is an artist and the tubes are way curvier than functional systems need to be. While I agree that larger capsules have existed, they require much greater pressure and wider bends. Do you have a better citation for typical diameters?

Comment: That video was just to demonstrate the fact that speeds are not always as fast as Wikipedia claims.  In general, modern systems tend to have faster speeds than older ones (better materials are available) and smaller capsules tend to travel faster than larger ones.  For diameters, [Parsian Medical Co](https://parsianmedical.com/pneumatic-tube-system-pts/) use capsules of 60mm to 300mm diameter. The Hamburg mail capsule we saw in the museum there was about 4 ft long.

Comment: The Mattel Inc Stock certificate is there because the clip is from the 'Barbie' episode of [The Toys that Made Us](https://www.netflix.com/gb/title/80161497) Netflix documentary.  Unfortunately, the OP hasn't responded about whether the source of the clip is listed in the credits at the end of the episode.

Comment: Capsules can be bigger and slower than typical, rail carriages do not need the tapering. Slower might be a good thing, if you transport delicate contents, (in this case magnetic tapes from accounting to archive?) The light reflections at the bottom of the tube, near the lamps, and distortions all the way, typical for a tube: how do you explain them? (Disclaimer: I thought of rail before as well, but discarded it completely after repeated looking)

Comment: @LangLangC The rail carriages [here](http://www.sammlungsiemensberlin.de/sammlung.php?id=79/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telelift) (last image) are tapered and very closely resemble the one in question, unlike any pneumatic capsules shown so far.

Comment: I can see now some capsules pictured are tapered, but they also have distinct thicker bands at the front and back (to create a perfect seal in the tube), which the original box does not.

Comment: @ledge good point, no seal is visible.

Comment: @LangLangC Sure, use cases do exist for large and slow capsules. What is surprising about light reflecting off a hypothesized metal rail? Its apparently varying width also seems correlated with the light sources.

Comment: A bit heavy variation of the reflections on a supposed rail. But the kicker are the variations of lighting itself as they are distorted on the left half of the image, as well as the colour gradient of the *background* above the "rail" or behind the tube. Rails do not influence what we see above them in office temperatures.

Comment: @LangLangC I don't understand what you describe seeing on the left half. Couldn't a rail cast a shadow when the light around it is diffuse -- as those flush ceiling units are meant to do? The open top side of the rail would be much less reflective than the sides.

Comment: All ceiling units have straight lines around them, but they get wobbly when behind the tube. On the left, this lens effect, above a rail/behind the tube (behind in the sense of: straight line from camera) is most pronounced: the lamp unit seems to bulge towards the lower left? (What is *in favour* of the rail theory is the shadow of the box on the ceiling, that means light coming from below; is it reflected from somewhre, the tube bottom, or rail bottom, but blocked by the box? Which is which?) I really wish someone went digging for the source of this stock clip.

Comment: @LangLangC The video is overexposed at the white end of the dynamic range: bright light is washing out neighboring areas in the video. Thus the white bulges that bow out straight lines and spill outwards from the places the rail most reflects the light towards the camera.

Comment: Not convinced enough to agree, as the upper edge of tube and the gradients (most clearly around the hanger but everywhere) aren't explained by this. But this line of reasoning fits well *into* the answer?

Answer (score 5):

The clip looks like it's from a movie, carefully framed to show this exotic looking gizmo. I think it's a movie effect.

The large diameter transparent tube with no visible supports or joints is unlike any pneumatic tube system I can find depicted. Also the diameter of the tube is much larger than the capsule, implying it has unreasonably thick walls.